# Laravel generate secure https URL from route

Tags: url, laravel, https, routes

**Edit**

I can't really find a way to generate a secure URL from route name.

To get a full URL, I use

```
echo route('my_route_name');
```

But what to do, if I want a URL with https?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Laravel Project to use HTTPS for all routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827062/how-to-force-laravel-project-to-use-https-for-all-routes)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually turns out, that laravel doesn't care if url is secure or not, because it generates based on the current url. If you're on https page, `route()` will return secure url. If on http, then `http://` url

The problem was, that Laravel didn't detect that https was enabled, which was due to faulty server configuration.

You can check if Laravel sees the current connection as https by calling `Request::isSecure();`

Comment: For those who are using Laravel behind a load balancer or other proxy, `Request::isSecure()` will always return false, unless you trust the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header from your proxy server. See: [Laravel Tricks - Fix SSL in Laravel 4+](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/fix-ssl-in-laravel-4-when-server-is-behind-a-load-balancer-or-a-reverse-proxy)

Comment: @AdamLink God damn it, thank you so much. I searched for hours for this. I shall add some Google Keywords now in this comment: Laravel http https nginx reverse proxy, laravel route relative url https.

Comment: In my experience using Laravel 5.2 on XAMPP/Windows does not generate https URL's with `route()` if the request uses https.
I noticed there's no `HTTPS` entry in `$_SERVER` so the protocol is not correctly detected.

Comment: Laravel 5.3 does not detect HTTPS even in Linux.

Comment: @DissidentRage probably your webserver is configured incorreclty. Check if $_SERVER has a field that indicates if https is on.

Comment: It doesn't work if I use ``route`` on email template.

Comment: @tirtakeniten check your .env file, what is the domain URL specified? It should be with https, not http

Comment: @Mārtiņš Briedis It worked, just a stupid code that I missed. Thank you

Answer (score 94):

**UPDATE:** As pointed out in the comments, a simpler way of doing this would be adding `URL::forceSchema('https');` for Laravel version between 4.2-5.3 or `URL::forceScheme('https');` for version 5.4+ in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider` file.

**Old answer:**

It's actually entirely possible and there's only one line of code needed to accomplish that.

Laravel doesn't check the presence of SSL by itself, it depends on Symfony. And there goes our key to making it believe that the current request is secure.

The thing is, we have to set the `HTTPS` `server param` to true and the easiest method is to paste the following code in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
```

In my very case, I only need to force SSL in production, the local env should still work on http. This is how I force SSL only on production:

```
$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', $this->app->environment() != 'local');
```

By the way, mind those terms, you may need them in the future.

Comment: This will actually trick the whole environment to think that the request came from https, which can be a security concern. I would recommend forcing https via `URL::forceSchema('https')` instead.

Comment: UPDATE: Laravel 5+ - Url::forceSchema changed to Url::forceScheme

Comment: This worked but for those who miss it at first like me, this is also needed at the top of the file: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;`

Answer (score 32):

Laravel 8

I recently resolved this by modifying this file:

`app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

in the method `boot()` add the following:

```php
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Add the use in the top:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

to work in your local environment you can leave it like this:

```php
public function boot()
{
    if(env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

Note: Don't forget to set your env variable `APP_ENV` with `prod` for the production file.

```sh
APP_ENV=prod
```

Comment: ive been trying many solutions but nobody reminded me about APP_ENV=prod. Tyvm

Comment: Tried all the options. Used secure_url() too. But no help.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I used \URL::forceScheme('https'); (inverted slash before URL variable)

Comment: You should replace env('APP_ENV') with config('app.env')

Answer (score 13):

As I mentioned in a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50682278), I found 5 ways of how to generate secure URLs.

1. Configure your web server to redirect all non-secure requests to https. Example of a nginx config:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name example.com www.example.com;
       return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
   }
   ```
2. Set your environment variable `APP_URL` using https:

   ```
   APP_URL=https://example.com
   ```
3. Use helper [secure_url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-secure-url) (Laravel5.6)
4. Add following string to AppServiceProvider::boot() method (for version 5.4+):

   ```
   \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');
   ```
5. Implicitly set scheme for route group (Laravel5.6):

   ```
   Route::group(['scheme' => 'https'], function () {
       // Route::get(...)->name(...);
   });
   ```

   At the moment this way is not documented, but it works well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20322282)

Comment: @peterzurich Fixed with taking into account your comment

Answer (score 8):

I think there is only one way to do this.

To generate the secure URL to your named routes, you might want to pass in your route into the `secure_url` helper function.

```
secure_url(URL::route('your_route_name', [], false));
```

You can't really use the `route` helper function because it generates absolute URL (with `http://`) by default and it's `http` not the `https` version that you wanted

Comment: Do you have an idea, how to get https when redirecting from controller? `return Redirect::route('login')` I'm amazed how difficult this is :)

Comment: I think it's pretty much similar to the above method except that you might want to use `Redirect::to` and pass in the above code as the parameter.

Comment: That works, but a better solution would be to use the actual response object returned by the Redirect::route call and modify it to make it secure.

Answer (score 8):

Laravel 5.x will generate secure URL via route() helper if it detects the incoming connection is secure. Problem usually happen if the app is hidden behind load balancer or proxy (e.g. Cloudflare) since the connection between app server and load balancer/proxy might not be secure.

I am using Laravel Forge + Cloudflare now and this is the easiest way I could find to enable app thinking incoming connection is secure (not sure about other proxy).

1. Generate self signed certificate (see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs or http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/)
2. In Forge panel, insert your private key and cert via `Sites > your-site > SSL Certificates > Install Existing Certificate`.
3. Activate
4. In CloudFlare panel, `Crypto > SSL`, choose “Full” (not strict)
5. Done (it will take few minutes for the change to get propagated)

In short, connection between client and Cloudflare is secured by Cloudflare's own SSL. Connection between app server and Cloudflare is protected via your generated cert (thus the app is seeing 'connection' as secure.

You can apply the same principle with other stacks.

Answer (score 6):

Use secure_url:

```
secure_url(URL::route('your_route_name', [], false));
```

You will need to set URL::route to false in order to not return a full URL. Then use secure_url function generates a fully qualified HTTPS URL to the given path.

> From the UrlGenerator interface you can use URL::route

```
string route(string $name, mixed $parameters = array(), bool $absolute = true)

Get the URL to a named route.
Parameters
string  $name   
mixed   $parameters     
bool    $absolute   
Return Value
string
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/UrlGenerator.html

Comment: Would be nice to be able to generate secure url from full url that starts from 'http://...'

Answer (score 4):

In most cases routes should be generated with the same scheme your site was loaded with. Laravel automatically detects if request has `X-Forwarded-Proto` header and uses it to decide which scheme to use in generated route URLs. If your site is behind reverse proxy then you should add reverse proxy IP address to list of trusted proxies. https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy package helps to do this. It's [included](https://laravel-news.com/trusted-proxy) in Laravel 5.5. For example, my `config/trustedproxy.php` looks like:

```
<?php

return [
    'proxies' => '*',

    'headers' => [
    ]
];
```

I use it with nginx reverse proxy that has the following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com; 
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log;

  client_max_body_size 50m;

  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8002;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


  if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Replace `example.com` with your domain. SSL certificates was provided by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) with [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you very much! ♥

Comment: I have to say that Nginx's config is easier to understand than that of Apache

Answer (score 4):

On laravel 5.5.*
You only need to add https on your .env file
as AppServiceProvider already had function that checks if your APP_URL or app.url on your config has https on it.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
 public function boot()
 {

    \URL::forceRootUrl(\Config::get('app.url'));    
    if (str_contains(\Config::get('app.url'), 'https://')) {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly old, but someone like me will dump over here one day.

In your .env file define the APP_URL to use https instead of using http.  Because all laravel url are generated based on this variable.

```
    APP_URL=https://example.com
```

and wherever you want you can just say

```
{{ URL::route('my.route', params) }}
```

Or

```
{{ route('my.route', params) }}
```

With make sure all the routes are generated with secure protocol, add in the boot method of AppServiceProvider class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(UrlGenerator $url)
    {
        if (config('app.production')) {
            $url->forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference of future visitors:

The secure_url function doesn't correctly handle GET parameters. So, for example, if you want to convert the url that the user has visited into a secure url while retaining the GET fields, you need to use this:

```
secure_url(Request::path()).'?'.http_build_query(Input::all());
```

Particularly note the use of path() rather than url() - if you give it a full url, it doesn't replace the http at the start, making it efectively useless.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue while trying to generate a route as form action in Blade using Laravel 5.4.
Then I hit upon secure_url(), so I tried

```
{{ secure_url(route('routename', $args)) }}
```

This still returned a non-secure URL. :-(

After digging through the code and adding some debug logs, I finally figured out that secure_url does not change the incoming url argument, if it's already an absolute URL (including the scheme).

Fortunately route has an absolute flag as the third argument, and returns a relative URL if $absolute is passed as false.

Assuming /a/{id}/b is a named route "a.b"

```
route('a.b', 1)        : will return http://[domain]/a/1/b 
route('a.b', 1, false) : will return /a/1/b
```

Joining the two I arrived at :

```
{{ secure_url(route('routename', $args, false)) }}
```

As expected it generated https://[domain]/routeXXX

:-)

Comment: I tried \URL::forceSchema('https'); but got an error forceSchema not found.

Comment: It was confusingly renamed to "forceScheme" (note the last "e" letter) in newer Laravel version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with redirect trailing slashes after 2 hours of looking for a bug, just need to remove

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your application domain with the `https` protocol in the APP_URL of your .env file.

```
APP_URL=https://example.com
```

Then run route:cache

Answer (score -2):

Place this in your filters.php file and everywhere will be forced to https while retaining URL parameters:

```
//force ssl
App::before(function () {
if(!Request::secure() && App::environment() != 'local')
{
    $baseHost = Request::getHttpHost();
    $requestUri = Request::getRequestUri();
    $newLink = 'https://'.$baseHost.$requestUri;

    return Redirect::to($newLink);
}});
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. What happens to POST requests? If all of my routes are generated without https, then every link in the page will lead to a redirect.

Comment: Yeah I've never ran into that issue. When I generate my routes I typically use:

Comment: '"ajax": 
{
    "url": "{{ URL::route('getDepartmentTickets') }}",
    "type": "POST"
},'

To generate my routes and they already include https but I will look around my config other files to make sure I didn't do something else. Or maybe because the current page already has https so Laravel automatically just uses that. I'll play around with it and get back to you.

Comment: Also if you really are still having issues you could modify inside the IF statement to take all of the POST data and put it in a Session for the one request. They have a function Session::flash('key', 'value') that probably would work.

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#flash-data

Comment: Yeah Judging by your post up top it must be because my very first page(the landing page) of the application redirects and requires https before even logging into the system. Then from there out all of my URL routes are generated with https automatically? If this is true and you have a valid SSL cert I would just try to make the whole application https for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score -2):

According to the laravel documentation on the **url()** helper method.

> If no path is provided, a *Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator* instance is
>   returned

So you can use the **secure** method of the **UrlGenerator** class in the following way:

```
echo url()->secure('my_route_name');
```

Answer (score -5):

To generate a secure (https) route use the following built-in 'before' filter called 'auth':

For example:

```
Route::get('your-route', ['before' => 'auth', 'uses' => YourController@yourAction']);
```

Now when you output your link it will be prepended with 'https'