# How to force Laravel Project to use HTTPS for all routes?

Tags: php, ssl, https, routes, laravel-5

I am working on a project that requires a secure connection.

I can set the route, uri, asset to use 'https' via:

```
Route::get('order/details/{id}', ['uses' => 'OrderController@details', 'as' => 'order.details', 'https']);

url($language.'/index', [], true)

asset('css/bootstrap.min.css', true)
```

But setting the parameters all the time seems tiring.

Is there a way to force all routes to generate HTTPS links?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Place this in the AppServiceProvider in the boot() method

```
if($this->app->environment('production')) {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Comment: This is a good option, instead of updating any server file.

Comment: Thanks it worked laravel 7 and 8 perfectly thanks again

Comment: When I used this my email verifications no longer worked. When clicking the verification link, users would get a 403: Invalid Signature

Comment: @AmiteshBharti can you please help me look into this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72844902/deployed-laravel-website-on-digital-ocean-showing-blank-screen-and-attempting-to

Comment: Performance-wise, does it have any effect? Since it will be executed for every single request to the website.

Comment: Thank you this is the best answer. in addition to this the user might 

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

Comment: it worked laravel 10, thanks

Answer (score 45):

Here are several ways. Choose most convenient.

1. Configure your web server to redirect all non-secure requests to https. Example of a nginx config:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name example.com www.example.com;
       return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
   }
   ```
2. Set your environment variable `APP_URL` using https:

   ```
   APP_URL=https://example.com
   ```
3. Use helper [secure_url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-secure-url) (Laravel5.6)
4. Add following string to AppServiceProvider::boot() method (for version 5.4+):

   ```
   \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');
   ```

Update:

5. Implicitly setting scheme for route group (Laravel5.6):

   ```
   Route::group(['scheme' => 'https'], function () {
       // Route::get(...)->name(...);
   });
   ```

Comment: In my Laravel 5.7.26 *`5.`* somehow disabled the website, however ***`4.`* worked as charm** :)

Comment: I am hosting my site on HostGator and I went into the cPanel tools and modified my Laravel 5.7 code and performed number 4 and when I go to my site by just typing mysite.tech, I still get sent to the not secure verion of my site. If I implicitely type https://mysite.tech then it works. Any idea why 4 did not work?

Comment: `4.` Resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 41):

I used this at the end of the `web.php` or `api.php` file and it worked perfectly:

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Comment: I have a hostgator account hosting my laravel app. If I put this in Routes/web.php, it doesn't re route my site to https and the ssl cert is on.

Comment: Have you checked for a .htaccess file? You could force https redirection there too.

Comment: I have two htaccess files, one in my main app directory and the other in my public DIR. I added the code in the post below yours into my main app .htaccess file. Should I also add it in my public .htaccess?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the one is working. Cause that's the place of the index.php file. How does your url index page end? Anyway if that doesn't work for you, HostGator has an impressive support, you could comment their answer as well.

Comment: So that WORKED :D, the only thing now though is that when the site reidrects it adds "/public/" to the end of the url. Do you know how I can trim that off?

Answer (score 37):

You can set `'url' => 'https://youDomain.com'` in `config/app.php` or you could use a middleware class [Laravel 5 - redirect to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https).

Comment: Middleware is the way to go. Setting the 'url' property didn't work for me (L 5.1).

Comment: this is still not satisfying. It only means that routes that lead to `http` will be forwarded to `https` routes but forwarding is detrimental to SEO rankings

Comment: This should be set by APP_URL variable in .env

Comment: I have APIs in my project will this run APIs as it is?

Comment: Can someone help me look into this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72844902/deployed-laravel-website-on-digital-ocean-showing-blank-screen-and-attempting-to

Answer (score 32):

Using the following code in your .htaccess file automatically redirects visitors to the HTTPS version of your site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: for laravel it should in public folder ... this is worked for me and other solution here didnt work on my cpanel server

Comment: FLAWLESS! This worked perfectly for me. Site uploaded to shared hosting on 18th MARCH, 2023. Laravel version 10.2.0.

Answer (score 26):

## Force Https in Laravel 7.x (2020)

---

> ***"2020 Update? Url::forceScheme was acting funky for me, but this worked liked a dime.**"*

---

1. **`https` code snippet**.

   resolve(\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::class)->forceScheme('https');

---

2. **Add that snippet within any Service Provider Boot Method**

---

- **1: Open** `app/providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`.
- **2: Then** add the https code snippet to the **boot** method.

```php
    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        resolve(\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::class)->forceScheme('https');

        parent::boot();
    }
```

- **3: Lastly** run `php artisan route:clear && composer dumpautoload` to clear Laravel's cached routes and cached Service Providers.

Comment: Did you still have to configure in `.htaccess` or this alone was enough?

Comment: THANKS! This is the only solution worked for me, I faced this issue only on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with load balancer. I think Laravel could not generate https toutes because the connection between the load balancer and the ec2 (ubunto server) is an http.

Comment: @Nhan did not have to configure .htaccess at the time, that may have been because it was already configured properly.

Comment: @Husam Interesting, I was working on an AWS project at the time of this post as well!

That being said - if I'm remembering properly - I used this https setup in local development.

I'm not sure if the other implementations didn't work because we had some AWS things happening locally or if it's just an interesting coincidence.

Either way, thanks for pointing out the AWS detail!

Answer (score 20):

Add this to your .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Replace www.yourdomain.com with your domain name. This will force all the urls of your domain to use https. Make sure you have https certificate installed and configured on your domain. If you do not see https in green as secure, press f12 on chrome and fix all the mixed errors in the console tab.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works! but adds `index.php` after domain name.

Comment: I am getting index.php after domain name too other way?

Comment: Any solution to avoid adding index.php at the end? it is breaking my routes

Comment: Anyone reading this, just replace 'RewriteEngine On'  with the above code in your.htaccess file

Answer (score 12):

Add this before the class name of this file **app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

Then paste this code inside the boot function of **app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php** file

```
if (config('app.env') === 'production') {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Comment: This helped me on Laravel 9.

Comment: That's nice to hear :)

Answer (score 10):

I would prefer `forceScheme` instead of doing it on a web server. So Laravel app should be responsible for it.

So right way is to add if statement inside `boot` function in your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
    if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```

Tip: to prove that you have APP_ENV configured correctly. Go to your Linux server, type `env`

This was tested on Laravel 5, specifically 5.6.

Comment: this worked for me inside the RouteServiceProvider, but not AppServiceProvider for some reason 

Comment: This worked for me too. the correct .env config for this is: `APP_ENV=production`

Answer (score 9):

For laravel 8, if you tried all of the above methods but got browser redirected you too many times error, please set proxies in `TrustProxies` middleware like the following:

**App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php**

```php
/**
  * The trusted proxies for this application.
  *
  * @var array|string|null
*/
protected $proxies = '*';
```

Answer (score 8):

```
public function boot()
{
  if(config('app.debug')!=true) {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
  }
}
```

in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: It is better to make condition based on environment (in this case non-local), not debug settings.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another option, this works on laravel 8.*. I'm not sure of lower versions though:

Add the `ASSET_URL` variable to your `.env` file.

For example:

```sh
ASSET_URL=https://secure-domain.com
```

You can find more info here: [Laravel Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset)

Hint: pay attention to the comments in the link above.

Comment: This worked this night!

Answer (score 6):

I figured out how to do this in a load-balanced infrastructure.

You need to add in you Nginx config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;

            add_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            add_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            add_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS "on";
            fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https";
    }
```

The importer pieces are the add_headers and pastcgi_params, it works like a charm through an AWS load balancer.

Comment: For some unknown reason, this is the only thing that worked for me. `HTTPS "on"` was the only thing I needed to add, although nginx includes a line like `fastcgi_param  HTTPS $https if_not_empty` but it did not work as expected, so I had to manually add this and force backend to use HTTPS;

Comment: Cheers! Solved the exact problem we were having on AWS load balancer.

Comment: `HTTPS on` turned out to be the only thing I needed. Instead of enforcing Laravel, this one is good and could perform better.

Answer (score 5):

In your .env file, just use

```
FORCE_HTTPS=true
```

This worked for me and you can also together set APP Url to https://your-site.com as an additional step

Answer (score 3):

try this - it will work
in RouteServiceProvider file

```php
    $url = \Request::url();
    $check = strstr($url,"http://");
    if($check)
    {
       $newUrl = str_replace("http","https",$url);
       header("Location:".$newUrl);

    }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to what is going on here.

Comment: need to call exit; after call header

Answer (score 3):

The better way to solute this issue is :
-> go to public folder,
->edit .htaccess
just add this code below :

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

-> and save.
-> close and re-open browser.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using .htaccess file to achieve https redirect? This should be placed in **`project root`** **`(not in public folder)`**. Your server needs to be configured to point at project root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Force SSL
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   # Remove public folder form URL
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: your vhost have to point public directory it self to do not expose website content in case of apache malfunction

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Apache server, the most efficient I think just change the virtual host configuration.
Change it like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.yourdomain.com
   Redirect / https://www.yourdomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName www.yourdomain.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it is not enough in my case (apache proxy -> php/nginx container with laravel 8.x), I have Letsencrypt certificate and virtualhost are ok, I should configure `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php` to add local IP proxy and it should be present in `protected $middleware` in `app/Http/kernel.php`

Answer (score 0):

Use the function **secure_url()** from laravel 5.2

```
$url = secure_url('user/profile');

{{ secure_url('your-link') }} //instead url()
```

reference [laravel secure_url() function](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-secure-url)

Answer (score 0):

No need for long process: simply go to your `config/admin.php` and set this to yes. If it's not there, add it.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Access via `https`
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your page is going to be accessed via https, set it to `true`.
|
*/
'https' => env('ADMIN_HTTPS', true),
```