# Laravel on https domain respons from http

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-socialite, dingo-api

I'm trying to implement facebook auth using SPA - Angular 6 and backend API - Laravel with Dingo/API.

When I try to redirect and return to SPA the page

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
    }
```

By some reason response comes from `http` instead of `https` according to error.

> [blocked] The page at https://www.domain/ was not allowed to display insecure content from http://api.domain/auth/facebook.

Although, I've set up my domains both to be on `https` and redirect all `http` requests to `https`. Moreover, I'm calling `https://api.domain/auth/facebook` with GET method.

Comment: did you checked your redirect url specified in either your route file or in your developer console of facebook

Comment: indeed. It also uses https. Moreover, I've specified that is set is up so that http requests are redirected to https

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827062/how-to-force-laravel-project-to-use-https-for-all-routes/50682278), there are few ways to make laravel work using https protocol:

1. Configure your web server to redirect all non-secure requests to https. Example of a nginx config:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name example.com www.example.com;
       return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
   }
   ```
2. Set your environment variable `APP_URL` using https:

   ```
   APP_URL=https://example.com
   ```
3. Use helper [secure_url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-secure-url) (Laravel5.6)
4. Add following string to AppServiceProvider::boot() method (for version 5.4+):

   ```
   \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');
   ```
5. Implicitly setting scheme for route group (Laravel5.6):

   ```
   Route::group(['scheme' => 'https'], function () {
       // Route::get(...)->name(...);
   });
   ```

Comment: APp url is set in that way

Comment: Also tried to set `$api->group([
            'version' => 1,
            'middleware' => 'api',
            'scheme' => 'https',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ],` still not working