# Laravel: how to generate https url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and have a question.
Is it possible to generate an https URL of the specific URL? I have a URL, e.g: login, and want to open it in https, not HTTP.
how can I force Laravel to open `url('login')` in https mode?

Comment: Serving the page over `http` vs `https` is configured by your server, not by Laravel.

Comment: @TimLewis I've configured both http and https. I don't want to redirect http to https at all I just want to redirect some http url to https.

Comment: The answer below suggests there a way, and I can't say I know enough about server administration for this, but it seems weird to me to have some routes use `http` but others use `https`. I would think that if you have `https`, everything should use it. See if that works for you though.

Comment: @TimLewis actually my default URL uses Http and I only want some specific URL use https. btw thank you and the below answer helped me

Comment: Interesting setup; definitely isn't something I've seen before, but glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is helper `function secure_url()`. The `secure_url` function generates a fully qualified HTTPS URL to the given path for e.g

```
$url = secure_url('user/profile');
```

Comment: Thanks, This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only some links in https, you can try this (force a group of routes to https):

```
Route::group(['scheme' => 'https'], function () {
    // Route::get(...)->name(...);
});
```

Similar to this question: [How to force Laravel Project to use HTTPS for all routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827062/how-to-force-laravel-project-to-use-https-for-all-routes)