# Use https on Laravel route in Blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade template that includes a form and the forms action is a Laravel route with a name.

`<form method="POST" action="{{ route('send-email') }}">`

When this is compiled on my webpage the route is http but I want it to be https e.g.

`<form method="POST" action="http://myexamplesite.com/send-email">`

How can I change it so it always uses https?

like: `<form method="POST" action="https://myexamplesite.com/send-email">`

My routes file:

`Route::post('send-user-email', 'SendUserEmailController@store')->name('send-email');`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827062/how-to-force-laravel-project-to-use-https-for-all-routes      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https

Answer (score 0):

in your .env file define your url with https:

```
APP_URL=https://yoursite.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel basically appends the routes to the app URL from your .env file, so to make changes you need to add HTTPS in **APP_URL** of in the **.env** file of your project

Example
`APP_URL=https://mycoolsite.org`