# Preventing http access in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, http, https

I have a question about force using HTTPS in laravel, i've added a condition inside AppServiceProvider.php, creating a middleware and modifying the .htaccess file. But I can still access the http page. Is there any other way to get laravel to redirect to https instead of http, and how to prevent user to acces the http addres? thank you!

my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

AppServiceProvider.php :

```
public function boot()
{
    if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
        $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS','on'); // this line

        URL::forceSchema('https');
    }
}
```

HttpsProtocolMiddleware :

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->secure() && app()->environment('production')) {
        return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
    }
    
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Laravel Project to use HTTPS for all routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827062/how-to-force-laravel-project-to-use-https-for-all-routes)

Comment: @KenLee no, it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this at the top of your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```