# Make Laravel use HTTPs by default

Tags: laravel, ssl

I deployed my website, and used this code to enforce that the protocol used is HTTPs
`\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');`
in the AppServiceProvider.

When I visit my website, it uses HTTP by default and I have to manually change 'http' to 'https' in the address bar and then the SSL certificate works fine and I can fill all forms securely.

How can I enforce that when the user visits the website, HTTPs runs not HTTP

Comment: What is your APP_URL value in your .env file - it should be https://yourdomain.com

Comment: I will try that, thank you!

Comment: have your webserver redirect requests from http to https

Comment: I did that in a middleware, but I get an error 
"WEBSITE DOMAIN redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Laravel Project to use HTTPS for all routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827062/how-to-force-laravel-project-to-use-https-for-all-routes)

Comment: have the webserver do it, not laravel

Answer (score 1):

Pls try this,

Create file HttpsProtocol.php locate in app/Http/Middleware, add below code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HttpsProtocol {

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->secure()) {
       return redirect()->secure('/');
    }
       return $next($request); 
    }
}
?>
```

add this line to $middlewareGroups section in app/Http/Kernel.php

```
\App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class,
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag to your root page head section.(home.blade.php,welcome.blade.php ...)

```
<head>
... other tags
    @if(env('APP_ENV') === 'production')
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
    @endif
</head>
```

And inside boot function app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php Add :

```
 public function boot()
    {
      if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
          $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');`
however, my first page was still loaded in HTTP and other subsequent requests were in HTTPs.

To fix this, I redirected the route at "/" to a clone route "/welcome" which returns the view which "/" was supposed to return.
From that point onwards HTTPs is used.

I could not redirect HTTP to HTTPs in the server because I use Elastic beanstalk and the proposed commands in the /.ebextensions config file didnt work, so my solution is as close to fixing the problem as I could get