# Heroku error : This request has been blocked; the content must be served over

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, heroku

I've deployed my laravel app to heroku. I have this file below as my frontend.blade.php but somehow heroku is throwing me this error message to the chrome developer console.

Error:

> geeksolution.herokuapp.com/:18 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/frontend/css/main.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
> geeksolution.herokuapp.com/:22 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/frontend/css/app.minify.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
> geeksolution.herokuapp.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/frontend/js/app.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
> geeksolution.herokuapp.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/frontend/images/content/favicon.png'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
> site.webmanifest:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> site.webmanifest:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
> geeksolution.herokuapp.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/frontend/css/main.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
> geeksolution.herokuapp.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://geeksolution.herokuapp.com/frontend/css/app.minify.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
> site.webmanifest:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

frontend.blade.php :

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Geek Solution</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ url('/frontend/images/content/favicon.png') }}" />
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('/frontend/css/main.css') }}" />
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url('/frontend/images/content/favicon.png') }}" />

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000" />
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"><link href="{{ url('/frontend/css/app.minify.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

Comment: replace your stylesheet link with secure verison (https instead of http) You can't load http ressources in a https pages with all modern browsers. Change your app base url in config or .env

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Laravel Project to use HTTPS for all routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827062/how-to-force-laravel-project-to-use-https-for-all-routes)

Answer (score 1):

This will be due to a server misconfiguration which has prevented laravel from knowing that your app is running over https.

See [Laravel generate secure https URL from route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426423/laravel-generate-secure-https-url-from-route) on how you can force secure link generation.

Anywhere you are using the `url` method should be changed to the `secure_url` helper method https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-secure-url

Comment: you dont have to use `secure_url()`, the `url()` method will use https if the request and your configured base url are in https. there is a downside of using `secure_url()` in your project, maintaining the code in your local environment without setting up proper server can be very painfull